Weak formulation for $-u''+u=1$
I am trying to solve the following problem.

Now, based on other examples I have seen, it seems the weak formulation should be something in terms of an inner product. In particular, we see
$$(-u+1,v)=(-u'',v)=\int_0^1(-u''(x))v(x)dx=(-u'(x)v(x))\vert_0^1+\int_0^1 u'(x)v'(x)dx=(u',v')$$
assuming $v(0)=0$ and $u$ is a solution to the ODE. So I believe the weak formulation should be to find $u\in V$ such that for all $v\in V$ $(-u+1,v)=(u',v')$ where $V=\{v\in H^1(0,1):v(0)=0\}$. Is this correct? Alternatively, it might be with $V=\{v\in C[0,1]:v\text{ is piecewise linear and }v(0)=0\}$, though I am not sure.
For the second part, I believe we let $V$ be the set of piecewise continuous functions which are linear on $[0,0.5]$ and $[0.5,1]$ and such that $v(0)=0$. This has a basis of two elements $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$. Then I let $u=c_1\varphi_1+c_2\varphi_2$ and plug it into the variational formula (weak formulation) and solve a linear system for $c_1$ and $c_2$. Is this right?

looks correct ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

That is almost correct,  but you have missed the derivative boundary condition that should appear on the right hand side. Following your integration by parts we have
$$\int_0^11\cdot v=\int_0^1(-u'' + u)v=(-u'v)|_0^1+\int_0^1u'v'+uv=-1\cdot v(1)+\int_0^1u'v'+uv.$$
Rearranging we get
$$\int_0^1u'v'+uv=\left(\int_0^1 v\right) +v(1). $$
Note that a weak form is typically always written with a bilinear form on one side and linear form on the other (for linear problems).
